# I am trying to add times. I get <__main__.MyTime object at 0x039C55C8>. But I am expecting my two times to add

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
class MyTime:

    def __init__(self, hrs, mins, sec):
        total_sec = hrs*3600 + mins*60 + sec
        self.hours = total_sec // 3600
        remaining_sec = total_sec % 3600
        self.minute = remaining_sec // 60
        self.sec = remaining_sec % 60

    def to_sec(self):
        return self.hours*3600 + self.minute*60 + self.sec

    def increment(t1, t2):
        secs = t1.to_sec() + t2.to_sec()
        return MyTime(0, 0, secs)
   
t1 = MyTime(9, 14, 30)
t2 = MyTime(3, 35, 0)

print(t1.increment(t2))
```

Comment: You did successfully add your two times.  However, since you did not define a `__str__()` or `__repr__()` method on your class, Python has no idea how to meaningfully display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning and printing the object.

If you want to print the seconds then you should do:

```
print(t1.increment(t2).to_sec()) # 46170
```

---

If you want a more detailed time, then add this method to your class:

```
def __str__(self):
    # or return anything you like, usually descriptive
    return str(self.hours) + ":" + str(self.minute) + ":" + str(self.sec)
```

And print it normally:

```
print(t1.increment(t2))
```

`__str__` will be called when you try to print to object.